# grabbing the closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am working on a gallery where i need to add a class to image when the overlay div is hovered.

this is my html

```
 <div class="overlayForCarDetails"></div>
 <a href="img/car_details/1large.jpg" rel="shadowbox">
   <img class="mediumImg" src="img/car_details/1medium.jpg" alt="">
 </a>
```

And this is my javascript

```
        $('.overlayForCarDetails').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.7');
            $(this).closest('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');

        });
```

But somehow its not working.
Can you tell me where am i doing it wrong.
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `.next()` and `.find()` instead of `.closest()` (as closest look up hierarchy), like below :

```
$('.overlayForCarDetails').mouseenter(function () {
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.7');
            $(this).next().find('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');

        });
```

Comment: @designerNProgrammer, because closest traverse up in DOM strusture ie it looks for parent see this http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 3):

Try to select the `.next()` sibling and `.find()` the relevant element from it.,

```
$(this).next('a').find('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');
```

Full code would be,

```
 $('.overlayForCarDetails').mouseenter(function () {
   $(this).css('opacity', '0.7');
   $(this).next('a').find('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `nextAll()`, or `siblings()` to get the `a` elements at same level in the hierarchical tree of DOM. Then you need to using `find()` to get the `.mediumImg` in the descendants of `a`   The `closest()` looks the ancestors of element on the DOM hierarchy.

```
$('.overlayForCarDetails').mouseenter(function () {
     $(this).css('opacity', '0.7');
     $(this).next('a').find('.mediumImg').addClass('zoomed');
});
```

[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

**Description:** Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Comment: `mediumImg` is a child of `a`.. See the html

Comment: Are you sure @RajaprabhuAravindasamy, he has <div class="overlayForCarDetails"></div>